# Error in Getting month -1 when month = 1 in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a textbox that displays the Monthname of the month selected by the user but it's always minus 1. I am having an error when January was selected cause it should display December. So what I did is this:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Month.Value<>1,MonthName(Parameters!Month.Value-1),"December")
```

But this doesn't solved the error. Could anyone help me what I am missing here?

My parameter month value is integer (1-12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this: `=IIF(Parameters!Month.Value<>1,MonthName(Parameters!Month.Value-1),"December")`

I'm only guessing here but I suspect it is trying to evaluate `MonthName(0)` When you pass it 1 and it causes and error:

What I did was this: `=MonthName(IIF(Parameters!Month.Value<>1,Parameters!Month.Value-1,12),False).ToString()`

And it seems to work.

This also worked: `=MonthName(IIF(Parameters!Month.Value<>1,Parameters!Month.Value-1,12))`

Comment: Thanks for your insights kamram. I will probably try your solutions in the future if the error still occur. Right now my script just worked when I changed the fieldname I am using. It's weird haha